# visual studio able to save state for multiple indivisual files not in solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Often I use Visual studio to edit standalone files (not in a project). So usually I will have like say 6 files opened (3 html files, 1 css file, 2 js files etc)

And the problem is that whenever i close visual studio, I have to locate and re-open all 7 files again (which is a bother really).

Is there a way for us to like save all 7 files in a *state file* and simply when i open that *state file* it will open all the 7 files in whatever order I have last saved them as ?

If you have used Notepad++ you will know what I'm talking about, basically when we close Notepad++ and open it the files that were previously opened stay opened, some sort of functionality like this.

Comment: Sounds like you could write an Add-In for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two Visual Studio macro methods that should do exactly what you need.

SaveAll() saves all open files and writes a file named status.txt to C: in which all open files are written separated by semicolon (totally independent of project/solution):

```
Sub SaveAll()

    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To DTE.Documents.Count
        text += DTE.Documents.Item(i).FullName + ";"
        DTE.Documents.Item(i).Save()
    Next i

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\status.txt", text, False)

End Sub
```

Next time, when you want to open those files, you simply call OpenAll(). It reads the status file, splits the semicolon separated text, and opens all files:

```
Sub OpenAll()
    'Open status file
    Dim text As String
    text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\status.txt")

    Dim files As String()
    files = text.Split(";")
    Dim file As String
    For Each file In files
        If file.Length > 0 Then DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(file)
    Next
End Sub
```

It's easy enough to modify this according to your needs (or even add a file dialogue). Thanks for asking this question, it made me focus on the VS macro IDE again and see how powerful it is.

Comment: thanks, this is rather powerful =D Btw is the information for the *position* of a file exposed to us? Like  I want to open the files in the same *position* as they were when they were saved.

Comment: The position is an ugly issue - I don't know any reliable property. The DTE.Windows collection is misleading, too. The tab order solely depends on how you opened the documents first, and that is what is saved. No convenient reordering. A completely different approach might be to automatically create a temporary, hidden project and automatically add your set of files.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have a temporary or  scratch solution for adding these files to, and when you've finished working on them (after days or weeks or whatever) just remove them. Solution files are probably a bit much for this, but you wouldn't have to do any extra work.

Otherwise look at making the recently opened files list a bit longer so they stay in there for longer.

Or use another editor for this purpose.  I use Notepad++ for all my non-solution/non-project related files.  If you close it without closing the individual files they remain in the editor next time you open it.  It's faster and lighter weight than VS too.

Comment: i don't like the idea of creating a new project just to host the stand-alone files. since the files may not be logically related to any single project, but rather just a random set of files that I would often like to have opened (abit like your description of the situation with notepad++). The recently opened files is annoying because I have to locate and click once for each file.